# How to use a locally installed plugin as a global sbt plugin

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to use a modified version of an sbt plugin (specifically, [sbt-quickfix](https://github.com/dscleaver/sbt-quickfix)).
After cloning the repo and compiling a modified version, I tried

1. Setting the version to `0.4.1-SNAPSHOT`, doing `sbt publishLocal` and adding a corresponding `addSbtPlugin` line to `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt`
2. Creating the following `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/project/Build.scala`:

   ```
   import sbt._
   import sbt.Keys._

   object PluginDef extends Build {
     override val projects = Seq(root)
     lazy val root = Project("plugins", file(".")) dependsOn (quickfixPlugin)
     lazy val quickfixPlugin = uri("file:///Users/ohle/Projects/sbt-quickfix/")
   }
   ```

Using both approaches, I still get an unmodified version of the plugin included in my sbt projects (i.e., the plugin behaves exactly like an unmodified one, and a simple String key I added for testing purposes isn't defined).

Why could the local version still be overridden by the official one?

P.S.: I use scala 2.10 and sbt 13.0 for everything.